# Switch - Why does using break give me an access violation writing location?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, access-violation

Alright so this code is pretty long over a short problem so I will kinda use <--- arrows to point it out for you, but down in my switch case WM_COMMAND:

I am kinda confused on using the return 0/ break.

`return 0;` seems to jump me outside of the whole WndProc function (skips over some code)

`break;` just breaks out of the switch statement but continues.

So does that mean I should use `return 0;` at the very end of my switch statement to prevent from moving on? Or is there something just wrong with my WM_MAXMININFO, because I never had that problem until after I changed the return 0 to `break;` The reason I ask is because once it hits WM_MAXMININFO I get a Access Violation. (That may be that cause of all of this).

```
// Win32Project2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Win32Project2.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windowsx.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include "ProcessFind.h"
#include <WinUser.h>

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#define BUTTON L"button"
#define szDefault L"Awaiting Commands..."

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdShow, int iCmdLine)
{
    wchar_t szAppName[] = L"Game Launcher";
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

RegisterClass(&wndclass);

hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, L"GameLauncher v1.0", WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 375, 100, NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0);

ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdLine);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{

static HWND hUserBox;
static HWND hWindowButton;
HBITMAP hImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"?C:\\Users\\chaos\\Desktop\\Capture.PNG", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);

 switch (message)
 {

 case WM_CREATE:
     CreateWindowEx(NULL, BUTTON, L"Check for process", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX , 5, 35, 150, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)2, NULL, NULL);

    CreateWindow(BUTTON, L"Minecraft", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 250, 5, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)1, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindow(BUTTON, L"Options", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_DISABLED, 250, 30, 100, 25, hwnd, (HMENU)3, NULL, NULL);

    hUserBox = CreateWindow(L"static", L"Awaiting Commands...", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER, 5, 5, 240, 25, hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;

case WM_COMMAND:

    switch (LOWORD(wparam))
    {
        case 1:
        {
            wchar_t* szProccessToKill = new wchar_t[20];
            GetWindowText(hUserBox, szProccessToKill, 20);


            // Checking checked status on checkbox. (Say that 5 times fast lol)

            if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 2) == BST_CHECKED)
            {
                ProcessFind testFunction;
                SetWindowText(hUserBox, L"Ending process");
                Sleep(1000);
                testFunction.EndProcess(L"java.exe");
                SetWindowText(hUserBox, L"Launching Minecraft...");
                Sleep(1000);
                ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"MinecraftLauncher", NULL, L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Minecraft", 6);
                SetWindowText(hUserBox, L"Minecraft has launched sucessfully!");
                Sleep(1000);
                SetWindowText(hUserBox, szDefault);
            }

            else if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwnd, 2) == BST_UNCHECKED)
            {

                SetWindowText(hUserBox, L"Launching Minecraft...");
                HINSTANCE ErrorCode = ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Minecraft\\MinecraftLauncher", NULL, NULL, 1);

                int ErrorCodeInt = (int)ErrorCode;

                switch (ErrorCodeInt)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"The operating system is out of memory or resources.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                        break;

                    case ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"The specified file was not found.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                        break;

                    case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND: 
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"The specified path was not found.", L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                        break;

                    default: 
                        SetWindowText(hUserBox, L"Minecraft has launched successfully");
                        Sleep(1500);
                        break;
                    }
                SetWindowText(hUserBox, szDefault);
            }
            delete[] szProccessToKill;
            break; <--- **If this is not a return 0;**
        }

        case 3:
        {
            break;
        }

    default:
        break;
    }

    //Set Min / Max Width/Height size.
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO: <-- It will jump down here and give me an access violation error:
{
    MINMAXINFO* MMI = (MINMAXINFO*)lparam; 
    MMI->ptMaxTrackSize.x = 375;
    MMI->ptMaxTrackSize.y = 100;
    MMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = 375;
    MMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = 100;
    return 0;
}

case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;

default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
}

return 0;
```

}

**I will kinda shorten it up straight to the problem for you guys:**

```
    SetWindowText(hUserBox, szDefault);
            }
            delete[] szProccessToKill;
            break; <--- **If this is not a return 0;**
        }

        case 3:
        {
            break;
        }

    default:
        break;
    }

    //Set Min / Max Width/Height size.
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO: <-- It will jump down here and give me an access violation error:
{
    MINMAXINFO* MMI = (MINMAXINFO*)lparam; 
    MMI->ptMaxTrackSize.x = 375;
    MMI->ptMaxTrackSize.y = 100;
    MMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = 375;
    MMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you really sure it doesn't crash here: `delete[] szProccessToKill;`?

Comment: You have nested switch statements, so a break within a case of the inner switch statement falls through to the next case of the outer switch statement.  If you don't want to fall through within the outer switch statement, you need a break after the closing brace of the inner switch.

Comment: Yeah I went through it slowly and as soon as the first line hits 
"MMI->ptMaxTrackSize.x = 375;" 
I get the error. @ πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: You seem to be focusing on `case 1:` of the inner switch, but you need to think through all cases of the inner switch.  Have you left out code for other cases because it isn't written yet or because nothing should be done?  Should any cases of the inner switch cause fall through on the outer switch?

Comment: @ JSF I have added the extra break (I forgot all about that) so thanks it seems to be working now.

was it possible it was falling through and adding unneeded information into the WM_MINMAXINFO and causing it to have an error.

Comment: By "was it possible" you seem to be saying you fixed it but still don't understand the behavior before it was fixed.  The `break` from `case 1` of the inner switch (that you tagged in your original question) sends execution to the closing brace of that inner switch (the end of `case WM_COMMAND`).  It isn't just "possible" that the original code would fall through from there to `case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:`.  It is well defined behavior of C or C++ that it **WILL** fall through there.

Comment: I have insisted on a coding standard where I work that says below each `case` section other than the last, the code says one of `break;` or `\\ Fall Through` unless the `return` from that point is obviously unconditional.  Everyone knows "fall through" is the defined behavior when nothing prevents that.  But everyone forgets that when reading/debugging code.  The explicit reminder of `\\ Fall Through` **everywhere** that the missing `break;` is not a bug is important for maintainable code.